# RailsAdmin for rails3 (with devise) - only for admin view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Hey guys, I've been using https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin which uses devise for authentication...

I've edited my users table to have a user_role. I only want a user to be able to access the admin section if their role is admin, any idea how I can manage this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at CanCan?

Some links:

1. [using devise and can can](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/)
2. [ryan bates railscast on can can](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)
3. [cancan on github](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

ian.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, Cancan is going to definitely come in handy for this kind of thing. Particularly the 'load_and_authorize_resource' in your controllers that you want to protect will be worth looking into.

In addition, there are many ways to set up admins and roles, I personally handle them in the ability.rb model file this way...

def initialize(user)

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
if user.roles.include? Role.find_by_name('Administrator')
    can :manage, :all
elsif user.roles.include? Role.find_by_name('Editor')
    can :index, Admin
    can :manage, Article

 (etc)
```